# Pentaho Issue with Import / Export and File Repository API

Tags: pentaho-cde

I created a dashboard in pentaho CDE with some title and description.

Now when I call the api "pentaho/api/repo/files/[Path]/children?showHidden=false&filter=*.wcdf", I am getting file list with properties.

However, if I change the properties like title / description, and save the dashboard those changes are not getting reflected.

Also when I export these files and import into another folder, the description property is not coming in the api call.

What could be the reason and how to solve this?

Comment: Posted in http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?200710-Issue-with-Import-Export-and-File-Repository-API as well

Comment: If you want to change the title and description of the dashboard. We have to do saveas not save. If you click on saveas it will ask where you want to save that .wcdf file you have to select same location and same .wcdf file no need to change the file name. I think this solution will useful to you.

Comment: What if i export the files and import into another folder?

Comment: Nothing will happen....